# Best way to get distribute a small lookup file using Distributed Cache

Tags: java, caching, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

Which is the best way to get Distributed cached data?

```
public class TrailMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    ArrayList<String> globalFreq = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        URI[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf);
        Path getPath = new Path(cacheFiles[0].getPath());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(getPath)));
        String setupData = null;
        while ((setupData = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] parts = setupData.split(" ");
            globalFreq.add(parts[0]);
        }
    }
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Accessing "globalFreq" data .and do further processing
        }
```

**OR**

```
public class TrailMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    URI[] cacheFiles
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf);

    }
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<String> globalFreq = new ArrayList<String>();
        Path getPath = new Path(cacheFiles[0].getPath());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(getPath)));
        String setupData = null;
        while ((setupData = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] parts = setupData.split(" ");
            globalFreq.add(parts[0]);
        }

        }
```

So if we are doing like (**code 2**)  does that mean `Say we have 5 map task every map task reads the same copy of the data` . while writing like this for each map , the task reads the data multiple times am i right (5 times)?

code 1 : as it is written in setup it is read once and the global data is accessed in map.

Which is the right way of writing distributed cache.

Answer (score 0):

Do as much as you can in the `setup` method: this will be called once by each mapper, but will then be cached for each record that is passed to the mapper. Parsing your data for each record is overhead you can avoid, since there is nothing there that depends on the `key`, `value` and `context` variables you are receiving in the `map` method.

The `setup` method will be called per map *task*, but `map` will be called for each ***record*** processed by that task (which can clearly be a very high number).

Comment: So it is better to go with code 1 Am i right? Is second one a straight forward way? As the document of Distributed cache says "each node will be accessing say copy of data"  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Comment: I would definitely go with the first option: you can't avoid the fact that each task has to be parse the cache contents once, but once that is done, you can avoid doing it again for each record.

Comment: What will happen if the cache data size is too large.That cannot be stored in a list or some other way.There may be situation where we need to get large data in hand. For eg:(If I am not wrong, Pls correct me if I am wrong) KNN algorithm. Its model is same input data. While predicting we need to get the model data in hand for these situation we cannot rely on code 1 as it may caught heap space

Comment: If your data is too large to fit into the D-Cache, then an alternative would be to use a different type of join (map- or reduce-side. for example), instead of a replicated join.

Comment: But for eg: the algorithm like KNN we need to find distance of 1 input line across all the model data. so I think that cannot be turned into map-side join. Or else for model data we need to emit all data with same key